# Script times out after 240 seconds

Tags: php, nginx

I'm running an Nginx + PHP-FPM server and I have a script that is supposed to execute over 30 minutes.  After 240 seconds it ceases to function and returns a 502 Gateway error from Nginx.

PHP-FPM Log for the execution:

> [03-May-2013 19:52:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 2949, script
>   '/var/www/shell/import_db.php' (request: "GET /shell/import_db.php")
>   execution timed out (239.971196 sec), terminating
>   [03-May-2013 19:52:02] WARNING: [pool www] child 2949 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 540.054237 seconds from start
>   [03-May-2013 19:52:02] NOTICE:
>   [pool www] child 3049 started

Nginx log for the execution:

> 2013/05/03 19:52:02 [error] 2970#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection
>   reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   98.172.80.203, server: www.example.net, request: "GET /shell/import_db.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000",
>   host: "www.example.net"

I've run this script on an apache+suphp server and it executes flawlessly.  Nonethless, I am including:
`set_time_limit(0);` at the top of my script.

The max_execution_time according to `phpinfo()` is 1800 seconds (this was originally 300, I bumped it up to this in an attempt to get it working).

FastCGI Nginx Configuration:

```
## Fcgi Settings
include                        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_connect_timeout        60;
fastcgi_send_timeout           180s;
fastcgi_read_timeout           600s;
fastcgi_buffer_size            4k;
fastcgi_buffers 512            4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size      8k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size   256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors       off;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
# nginx will buffer objects to disk that are too large for the buffers above
fastcgi_temp_path              /tmpfs/nginx/tmp 1 2;
#fastcgi_keep_conn              on; # NGINX 1.1.14
expires                        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
```

I've restarted php-fpm and nginx to no avail.  What setting or configuration am I missing from this or that I could check?

Answer (score 0):

When you run nginx with php-fpm, nginx tries to so stay connected with php-fpm's children. You should set the following directive to change that:

fastcgi_keep_conn off;